# Calling a function to another activity Camera ImageView in Android

Tags: java, android

Is somebody know how to call a function from the other activity. I want to display an `imageView` by calling a function from the other activity. I just want to avoid duplicates and lessen the code by calling a method. This is what's going on

In my `secondActivity` I want a button calling a function from `firstActivity` which opens a camera  and then I want to display it to the secondActivity. It very helpful for me if somebody know how can I handle this problem

*Error:*

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
```

*The error is on this line method pickCamera() in firstActivity*

```
image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
```

I know, I just should use like this, this is what I tried but it conflicts my `onActivityResult`

```
MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
mActivity.pickCamera();
```

*SecondActivity* which called a function from firstActivity `pickCamera()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Button btnrescanBeneId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rescanBeneId);
    mPreviewCashCard = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String resultUri = extras.getString("CashCardImage");

        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(resultUri);

        // I want to display image here from the other activity URI

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),myUri);
            mPreviewCashCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     btnrescanBeneId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirstActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
            mActivity.pickCamera();
        }
    });
}
```

*FirstActivity* In this activity I also have a button `pickCamera` which display to another activity in `secondActivity` it has the same function button just like the word `Re-captureImage` by calling activity to the `firstActivity`

```
 btnrescanBeneId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickCamera();
            }
        });

public void pickCamera() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPic");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image to Text");
    image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode ==RESULT_OK){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            //camera
            i.putExtra("CashCardImage",image_uri.toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to from first activity->open camera-> get result -> open second activity -> return to first activity -> open camera again? Do you need to stay on second activity?

Comment: @МилошКојадиновић Thanks for your response ,Yes exactly! that I want, open camera from `firstActivity` and display on `Secondactivity` and open again in `SecondActivity through button and  display it again the ImageView in `SecondActivity`. I'm still searching but yet still don't know how to handle this.

Comment: @МилошКојадиновић open again in `SecondActivity` by just calling method  that comes from the `firstactivity`

Answer (score 0):

So, creating new Activity is not something you should do. Activities should be used with startActivity, or startActivityForResult. In case that you want to have same method in two Activities you should use inheritance. Something like this:

```
public abstract class HasCameraOpenerActivity extends Activity {

    private Uri image_uri;

    public void pickCamera() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image to Text");
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
    }

}
```

but then, you should start second activity with startActivityForResult, so when you return from second activity to the first one, you should set result like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("IMAGE_URI", image_uri);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

Then read it and set it in the field of first activity.
Communication between activity objects should not be done in standard way where you access object and pass data.

EDIT: You should use inheritance like this:

```
class MainActivity extends HasCameraOpenerActivity {

    private Button button;
    
   public void someFunction() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickCamera();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And for MainActivity2, also inherit:

```
class MainActivity2 extends HasCameraOpenerActivity
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, how can I call method in the same Activity? I just done like this image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itD0H.png)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have a question should I put your edited in my onCreate() on my `firstActivity` just like this image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmI7I.png) but it seems it didn't recognize the class? since the name of my Activity is `ScanCashCard`

Comment: Should I declare this line in my `secondActivity?`  `class MainActivity2 extends HasCameraOpenerActivity` Im still confused how I'm going to use your source.