# Calling function to the first Activity Camera in Android

Tags: java, android

I just want to call a function from the other activity and.I want to display an imageView by calling a function from the other activity. In the first activity, it has a function to scan Image and display the data to the `2nd Activity`.The problem is in `2nd Activity` I want to re-scan again the Cashcard `ImageView` by calling again the function that comes from `First Activity`, In short, I want to call the `Camera` function. Now I have two ImageView in `2nd Activity` and only one `onActivityResult` with it. If I click the `button re-scan under`  `cashcard` I want to call a function again from the first activity and reflect the data again to the `2nd Activity`. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Now I've been trying to use **Inheritance** but it didn't solve the problem for me.

*Reference: same problem with this link* [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69152488/calling-a-function-to-another-activity-camera-imageview-in-android)

I think I didn't apply the proper way of Inheritance

[image]
[image]

***First Activity***

```
  //Inside onCreate function
  class MainActivity extends HasCameraOpenerActivity {
      private Button button;
        public void someFunction() {
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pickCamera();
                }
            });
        }
    }

//outside onCreate function
public abstract class HasCameraOpenerActivity extends Activity {

    private Uri image_uri;

    public void pickCamera() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image to Text");
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
    }
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode ==RESULT_OK){

            //camera image pass to 2nd activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            i.putExtra("CashCardImage",image_uri.toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

**Second Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

Button btnrescanCashCard= (Button) findViewById(R.id.rescanCashcard);
mPreviewCashCard = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String resultUri = extras.getString("CashCardImage");

    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(resultUri);

    // I want to display image here from the other activity by calling using URI above

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),myUri);
        mPreviewCashCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 btnrescanCashCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //should I use this?, to call function to first Activity?
        FirstActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
        mActivity.pickCamera();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: If you call SecondActivity from FirstActivity, you cannot access FirstActivity's instance and call methods from there (except static). Even if you ise fragments instead of activities, there may be errors. Please, redesign your architecture.

Comment: @CoolMind It works fine before but the inheritance didn't applied yet  , but the code above I'm just trying to applied it to inheritance, Is any other way? other than inheritance?